# Using Lodash chain and filter not returning filtered value

Tags: javascript, filter, lodash, chain

I am trying to use LoDash to filter an object where the key `state === accepted`. There are two objects in the `quoteList` array. The console.log is returning 2 objects in the array; I am expecting it to return 1 object where `state === accepted`. I am using `chain` because I will need to use other functions once I get this working.

```
let quoteList = shipment.quotes
const QuoteSlides = _
.chain(quoteList)
.filter(['state', 'accepted'])
console.log(quoteList)
```

Comment: You're logging `quoteList` not `QuoteSlides` which is the one with the lodash logic.

Comment: @Baruch Ah - thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Though you're logging the incorrect object (as mentioned in comments by @Baruch), you also have to unwrap the result using `.value()` function to get the actual result:

```
const QuoteSlides = _
  .chain(quoteList)
  .filter(['state', 'accepted'])
  .value()
```

Lodash creates a wrapper when you call `_.chain` on an object. This is called explicit chaining. `.value()` removes the wrapper and returns the actual result, which will be assigned to `QuoteSlides`.

See more of [implicit](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.5#lodash) and [explicit](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.5#chain) chain sequences.